# How do you make a item transporter in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Can you please help me on this topic? I just need basic facts about this.

Comment: by item transporter do you mean like a hopper network or something?

Comment: Ender chests..?

Comment: Please in future though expand apon your question as this was quite vague. I hope the answer will help if it doesnt please let me know what exactly you were looking to do

Comment: Hi ViczoidZ, welcome to Arqade! This is a very broad question, we prefer for people to have a go making stuff like this themselves, and come back if you get stuck with a specific problem. So saying that, what research have you done? Is there something specific you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends which direction you wish to move your items.

Item elevators can be made with pistons and solid blocks and you can use the example below
created by Etho

otherwise for horizontal movement you can use hoppers connected to eachother with a redstone input.

An old alternative(pre-Hoppers) is to use water but this is not a great choice as items will despawn if they have to travel too far or left for too long.

Though you could use a combination of hoppers and water, having the water flow into a hopper. This solution helps by not using as much iron. This would also help if you want to collect items dropped e.g. a wool or cactus farm